# Fatty Tuna vs. Tuna

Tags: sushi, tuna, sashimi

Why does fatty tuna cost more than lean tuna? Is it because some people think it tastes better?

[image: Fatty Tuna (front) vs. Lean Tuna (back)]

Comment: We don't address questions about "health" on this site. Is there a way you can ask this without inquiring about the health benefits?

Comment: As an example, you should be fine asking something like "Does fatty tuna actually have more fat than regular tuna?" This is quantifiable and doesn't require us to judge whether it's "more healthy".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the fatty part of the tuna is prized for its flavor, especially in Japan. They particularly like 'o-toro' tuna, so that drives the price up there and elsewhere.

[image: 1]

> Otoro represents a most enjoyable part of dining found in Japan, and a large number of bluefin tuna farmed all over the world land in typically the fish marketplaces linked to Japan, exactly where the o-toro will undoubtedly receive a more expensive price tag amongst sushi enthusiasts.

From [Otoro.com](http://otoro.com/)